# Convert LPCM buffer to AAC for HTTP Live Streaming

Tags: macos, audio, core-audio, audio-streaming, http-live-streaming

I have an application that records audio from devices into a Float32 (LPCM) buffer.

However, LPCM needs to be encoded in an audio format (MP3, AAC) to be used as a media segment to be streamed, according to the [HTTP Live Streaming specifications](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-23#section-3.1). I have found some useful resources on [how to convert a LPCM file to an AAC / MP3 file](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/iPhoneACFileConvertTest/Listings/AudioConverterFileConvertTest_ViewController_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010581-AudioConverterFileConvertTest_ViewController_h-DontLinkElementID_7)  but this is not exactly what I am looking for, since I am not willing to convert a file but a buffer.

- What are the main differences between converting an **audio file** and a **raw audio buffer** (LPCM, Float32)? Is the latter more trivial?

My initial thought was to create a thread that would regularly fetch data from a **ring buffer** (where the raw audio is stored) and convert it to a a valid audio format (either AAC or MP3).

- Would it be more sensible to do so immediately when the AudioBuffer is captured through a `AURenderCallback` and hence pruning the ring buffer?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

The core audio recording buffer length and the desired audio file length are rarely always exactly the same.  So it might be better to poll your circular/ring buffer (you know the sample rate, which should tell approximately how often) to decouple the two rates, and convert the buffer (if filled sufficiently) to a file at a later time.  You can memory map a raw audio file to the buffer, but there may or may not be any performance difference between that, and async writing a temp file.